# the environment in pycharm changes by itself when i upload a project from GitHub

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have a code that is written in python 2.7 and needs the package tensorflow 1.6, when I set the right environment and upload the project from github it automatically switches up to python 3.12 and the code doesnt run

nothing seemed to work to maintan the interpretor at 2.7.